# JQuery Mobile App Multi-Page - Reload page

Tags: html, cordova, jquery-mobile

i'm developin an App with Jquery Mobile + html5 + PhoneGap...i'm using a multi-page template...all my app's pages are in the same .html...somethings like this:

```
<!--********* HOME *************-->

<div data-role="page" id="home">
<div data-role="content">
.....
</div>
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" id="footer">
<a href="#menu" data-role="button" dataicon="home" data-transition="fade" id="credits"> </a>
</div>
</div>
<!--********* HOME *************-->

<!--********* MENU *************-->

<div data-role="page" id="home">
<div data-role="content">
.....
</div>
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" id="footer">
<a href="#menu" data-role="button" dataicon="home" data-transition="fade" id="credits"> </a>
</div>
</div>
<!--********* MENU *************-->
```

and so on...

in some pages i implement some animations...like the auto open for collapsible element

```
$(document).on('pageshow', '#mostra_menu, #regina_menu, #cultura_menu, #restauro_menu', function(){       
$('.ui-collapsible').children().next().hide();
$('.ui-collapsible').children().next().slideDown(300);
});
```

this works graet...the problem is that when i reload the same page - #mostra_menu,... - the collapsible is still opened...

same problem in other pages where i have an animated .gif...when i load for the first time the page the animation starts normally...if i navigae the app and then reload the page with the .gif the animation doesn't start...

i think the problem is in the multi-page html...it is loaded one time...so all the pages revisited aren't reloaded...

how i can fix?!

Comment: Try this attribute `data-dom-cache="false"` on pages.

Comment: Well, there are two other solutions, either set `data-ajax=false` which will disable Ajax totally. Or refresh the page using `$.mobile.change('#'+$.mobile.activePage[0].id, { allowSamePageTransition: true });` on pageshow.

Comment: Sorry Omar...i don't understand how to use the second solution...the first doesn't work for me...

Comment: add it inside your `.on('pageshow'` function. `$.mobile.change('#'+$.mobile.activePage[0].id, { allowSamePageTransition: true });`

Comment: sorry again...i put the code in


$(document).on('pageshow', '#mostra_menu, #regina_menu, #cultura_menu, #restauro_menu', function(){       
    $('.ui-collapsible').children().next().hide();
    $('.ui-collapsible').children().next().slideDown(300);
 $.mobile.change('#'+$.mobile.activePage[0].id, { allowSamePageTransition: true });
});


....but it crashes all the links...

Comment: sorry by bad `$.mobile.changePage` i forgot `Page`

Comment: ok...thanks...it reload the page...but it does something like a loop...the page is reloaded continuously...;(

Comment: How come I forgot this `$('[data-role=collapsible]').collapsible();` add it before you do the animation.